# Redirection 301 from /%postname%.html to /%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%.html

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, permalinks

I want to change the permalinks from `/%postname%.html` to `/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%.html`.

I know how to do that from Worpdress Admin panel. But I got more than 20000 post, so I want to know please if is any chance to make a redirection from .htacess for old my posts with `/%postname%.html` redirect to `/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this in WordPress itself (in contradiction to `.htaccess`) as you must fetch the real permalink based on the postname.

Please try updating your permalinks to the new structure and adding the following code to your **functions.php** file.

```
<?php
function redirect_postname_to_date_structure($wp) {
    $pattern = '#^([^/]+)\.html$#';
    $matches = array();

    if ( preg_match( $pattern, $wp->request, $matches ) ) {
        $slug = $matches[1];

        $args = array(
            'name' => $slug,
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => 1
        );

        // Try to retrieve post based on slug
        $posts = get_posts( $args );

        if ( $posts ) {
            $permalink = get_permalink( $posts[0]->ID );

            wp_redirect( $permalink, 301 );
            exit;
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'parse_request', 'redirect_postname_to_date_structure' );
?>
```

**PS:** I recommend that you test using the 302 status code (in `wp_redirect()`) at first. You can switch to 301 when you're confident it works.

Comment: Hello. I fix now. First I have a error because i forgot to remove a previously 301 redirection from the .htaccess Once I revome, is working fine. I check a old link on google and the done the redirection to the new permalink perfect without problems.Thank you so much

Comment: @user2143527 I'm glad you got it working. Please mark my answer if it helped you.

Comment: Hiya. I can't give a vote yet because Im new and the sistem said I need 15 reputation... Sorry. But once I got the reputation I need I will give the vote.

Comment: Hello again. I found on my Google Webmnaster more than 28000 404 error with trackback because the have the old permalink. Any idea how can I fix that as well, please? Regards